# Error projecting EPSG 31255 to LAEA with R Raster but not with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, r

I am trying to project a Rasterfile originally in EPSG 31255 - MGI / Austria GK Central to LAEA. The original data can be found here: https://e-gov.ooe.gv.at/at.gv.ooe.intramapgem/dop/downloads/40101/40101_DOM_tif.zip

I can project the data in QGIS without problem, but when I do so in R with the raster package, the resulting raster is slightly shifted compared to the original file:

[image]

This is my R code:

```
chm = raster::raster(path)
crs(chm) = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=-5000000+ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs"
crs_target = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"
chm_proj_ngb = projectRaster(chm, crs=crs_target, method = "ngb")
```

Why does such a shift happen only when using R and how do I project the raster correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R does seem to mess that up badly for me too. Not sure why. Possibly the underlying PROJ library, or possibly some problem in the CRS specification (there's a few warnings scattered about), or possibly its using a different transformation.

One way round this in R is to use the `gdalwarp` function from the `gdalUtils` package which operates on the TIFF file itself rather than an R raster object:

```
 gdalwarp("./G-S5337-73.tif","G-warp.tif",t_srs=crs_target)
```

This `G-warp.tif` precisely overlays the original in QGIS. One transformed in R with:

```
 chm_proj_ngb = projectRaster(chm, crs=crs_target, method = "ngb")
```

shows the offset.

If you have an R raster object you want to reproject with this, then save to a TIFF, `gdalwarp`, then read the TIFF into R.